# Faild to load DevExpress Report on visual studio

Tags: devexpress

i'm trying to open my project on another machine .. and i faced this problem

how to solve this error?

error:
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJFw9.jpg]

Comment: Try rebuilding the solution (clean it first)

Comment: You won't get much help if you don't provide any code.  You need to read this page about how to provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example : http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve